# Add class to collection_select on Ruby On Rails formulary

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, collection-select

I'm using a form for create a record in RoR. I've dropdown menu and I don't know how to add a class for styling this element.

Code:

```
<%= f.collection_select :id, TipusProducte.order(:nom),:id ,:nom, include_blank: false, class: "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" %>
```

But this class doesn't work, this style is from Bootstrap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing it right, but you need to separate the hashes:

```
<%= f.collection_select :id, TipusProducte.order(:nom),:id ,:nom, { include_blank: false }, { class: "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" } %>
```

Otherwise, it gets interpreted as one hash. The function spec has two object hashes as arguments; the first is for collection options, the second for HTML options.

Comment: Leaving this here as it answers the question, but consider @jvillian 's answer as well; you probably don't want to style your select drop-down as a button.

Answer (score 1):

In the Bootstrap dropdowns [docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/), the styles are always applied to a `button` element like this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But `collection_select` is going to give you `select`, like this:

```
<select name="post[author_id]">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">D. Heinemeier Hansson</option>
  <option value="2">D. Thomas</option>
  <option value="3">M. Clark</option>
</select>
```

I'm guessing HTML looks something like:

```
<select ... class = "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle">
```

And I suppose Bootstrap doesn't know how to do anything with that.